# Ubuntu wont boot, converting from windows 10

Tags: boot

I am converting from windows 10 to ubuntu and cannot get ubuntu to boot.

So far, I have formatted the usb with Rufus with the 20.04 build on my flash drive, chose to boot from the usb device, and restarted.

The last instance that was finished was Tell Plymouth to Write out Runtime Data.
After that, the next dependency loops in an error and restarts

Comment: It looks like you are saying that the install never completed? At the end of the install, you are instructed to unplug the USB and reboot.

Comment: Yes, right now its starting and stopping a journal service

Comment: Reboot into the USB and reinstall again.

Comment: Ok, now I have zfs volumes are ready and Load Apparmor profiles managed internally by snapd. Should I do this after each line is timed out?

Comment: Lines shouldn't be timing out in the first place. ZFS indicates that you are trying an unusual or complex install. Generally, I recommend that folks stick to the defaults on their first install - make your first install *successful* instead of *perfect*. After you see what a successful install looks like, you can go back and re-install, adding as much complexity as you like.

Comment: I followed the tutorial on Ubuntu for the install, so it should be the basic install. I'll try formatting the USB from FAT 32 to NTFS and try again.

Comment: 1) Why do you need NTFS formatting of the LiveUSB? 2) Did you checksum verify the ISO downloaded before creating the LiveUSB? https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu explains how.

Comment: It had worked for me previously, and that is the primary reason for me changing the formatting of the USB. And thank you for the checksum verification. I was unaware of that process. 
So far, just as an update I am still unsuccessful in installing.

Comment: Previously as in Windows throughout the years

Comment: In order to boot from an ISO file, do I need GRUB 2 installed on the computer?